# Computer doesn't turn on when pressing the power button

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, power

It's not that it doesn't boot, but that the computer simply doesn't turn on. Absolutely nothing happens when I press the power button. Strangely enough, at some point it does turn on. This time it turned on on its own!

I never had stability problems, the computer never did turn off when I was using it. Even now when it does start, it works well.

At first I suspected the power button. But now that its on, I tested. Every time I press the power button, the shutdown dialog appears. So the power button seems to be working well.

The computer is connected with a LAN cable to the motherboard; there are two LEDs. When I switch off the power supply, the LEDs go off, when I switch it on the LEDs start blinking again.

I guess it comes down to the motherboard or the power supply. Which one is more likely to be at fault here? Unfortunately, I don't have any replacement parts to test. I would have to order them. Where should I start?

Btw, I have the habit of disconnecting the computer from power at night via a power strip with a switch. Is that maybe not a good idea?

Comment: If this were my computer and based on your overall description, I would try a new power supply. You specifically said the computer works well and without issues.

Comment: You might be best to take it to your local repair shop. They should be able to quickly test and tell you. New motherboard generally means new computer.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess it comes down to the motherboard or the power supply. Which one is more likely to be at fault here?

I would suspect the motherboard. Since your LAN port LEDs start blinking when you switch on the power supply, the motherboard gets power delivered by the PSU. (BTW the blinking is not unusual)

You could try to update your motherboards bios/firmware before you order a new one. But this *might* be destructive on an already malfunctioning board.

> Btw, I have the habit of disconnecting the computer from power at night via a power strip with a switch. Is that maybe not a good idea?

I wouldn't see why. Have done that for years, too.